# Invoke multiple instance of class

Tags: c++

I have a class

```
class Command
{
 public:
  Command (uint32_t _count, uint32_t _pre)
    {
      count = _count;
      pre = _pre;
    }

  int parse (string command)
  {
         // Some action on the base of given string and pre initialized member
         // varaiable
  }

 protected:
  uint32_t pre;
  uint32_t pre;
};
```

Now I have multiple instance of Command class for different 'Command' type. i.e for simplicity I create instance name on the command type.

```
Command type1 (2,3);
Command type2 (6,5);
Command type3 (7,3);
```

Now, how can I call the 'parse' function of given 'type' in single line.

I can handle it with if else-if structure like

```
if (type == type1)
 type1->parse (cmd);
else if (type == type2)
  type->parse (cmd);
..
..
```

But can I handle this in a generic way? like

```
'type'->parse (cmd);
```

Comment: Are you familiar with inheritance and polymorphism?

Comment: Are you familiar with `std::vector` or arrays?

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what you want? Somehow, I don't think the answer you are looking for is "Yes, create a `Command&` and call it `type`"...

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here, but it looks like you want to use a polymorphic class...

Comment: It's funny how this vague problem statement has immediately resulted in several different interpretations of the question.

Comment: Even though he's using the term "type", they are of the same type so polymorphism doesn't necessarily apply.  Not sure inheritance applies either.  A simple array might be the easiest if the types are sequential... `type[x].parse(cmd)`

Comment: There is clearly an error in the code. type1 is an object, type has to be a pointer (type->), so type == type1 is deemed to produce compilation error.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Regarding the simplicity I'd say _@Thomas_ is on the right track.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Yeah, I think so, too.

Comment: I was interpreting it to mean different command types would require a different `parse` function implementation and hence the polymorphism but I agree the OP needs to clarify the question/problem.

Comment: @ChristianHackl /OT You're a good companion here BTW. I like most of your answers. Best greetings from Oktoberfest mad Bavaria ;-).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Why, thanks :) Have fun and behave like a good Stackoverflow citizen over there! ;)

Comment: @ChristianHackl _"Why"_ Just to encourage you at the track you're on, and because I love to see my Austrian _neighborhood_ here :-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use std::vector (with pointers):

```
std::vector<Command *> types;
types.push_back(new Command(2,3));
types.push_back(new Command(6,5));
types.push_back(new Command(7,3));
//...
unsigned int i = 2;
types[i]->parse(cmd);
```

At some point, you will need to delete the objects pointed to:

```
delete types[i];
```

**Edit 1:**
You can also use the `std::vector` without pointers, saving the need for deletion:

```
    std::vector<Command> types;
    types.push_back(Command(2,3));
    types.push_back(Command(6,5));
    types.push_back(Command(7,3));
//...
    types[i].parse(cmd);
```

With disclosure of details of purpose, we could present other options as well.

*Note:  per comments, added usage of `std::vector` without using pointers*.

Comment: While I don't see need for (raw) pointers, I think your answer is down the right track, regardless uncleanness of the question.

Comment: Raw pointers is simple.  The issue I saw was the three different constructions (parameters to the constructor).  I wasn't sure whether to use the copy construction (of an item on the *stack*) or go with a smart pointer.  Anyway, this gets the point across.

Comment: I also think that simple objects would be better. And the example misses the necessary `delete`s, which the OP is likely not aware of. And there is a typo (`push_back`, not `pushback`).